# how to integrate variable from pickle back to object

Tags: python, pickle

I have made I class, that is saving itself as a pickle.

I would like that class to be able to import the data back from a pickle... :

like :

```
myFirstInstance.printV1() #variable is set to 4 by the __init__
myFirstInstance.write2Pickle(myPickleFile.pkl)

mySecondInstance.loadPickleData(myPickleFile.pkl)
mySecondInstance.printV1() # should give 4 back from the firstInstance...
```

Comment: So... what's wrong with unpickling the data?

Comment: Unpickling doesn't overlay existing objects, it creates new ones with the same data that was pickled.

Answer (score 2):

Using `pickle` is as simple as:

```
import cPickle as pickle
with open('a.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(obj, f)
with open('a.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    obj = pickle.load(f)
```

If your class requires special logic for pickling/unpickling, you should override the methods used by the [pickle protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-normal-class-instances) (e.g. `__getstate__` / `__setstate__`). That way, the usage above still works.

Comment: It might be instructional to show how you suggest  `__getstate__` / `__setstste__` would work in the case the OP has defined.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky, as you are changing the state of a class instance from inside an existing instance… and also you want to pickle an instance of a class from within the instance of the class.  To make the pickling of class instances easier, I'd use `dill` instead of `pickle`.

```
>>> import dill
>>> 
>>> class MyClass(object):
...   def __init__(self, x):
...     self.V1 = x
...   def printV1(self):
...     print(self.V1)
...   def write2Pickle(self, filename):
...     with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
...       dill.dump(self, f)
...   def loadPickleData(self, filename):
...     with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
...       obj = dill.load(f)
...     self.V1 = obj.V1
...     # similarly for other instance state variables
... 
>>> myFirstInstance = MyClass(4)
>>> myFirstInstance.printV1()
4
>>> myFirstInstance.write2Pickle('myPickleFile.pkl')
>>> del myFirstInstance
>>> mySecondInstance = MyClass(1)
>>> mySecondInstance.printV1()
1
>>> mySecondInstance.loadPickleData('myPickleFile.pkl')
>>> mySecondInstance.printV1()
4
```

I'd note that it's probably better programming practice to not put the pickling and unpicking as a class method… unless there's a *really* good reason that it should be there.

Also, you could directly unpickle and get a perfectly good new instance, so unless you need to overwrite the state of an existing instance, again, no need to have the unpicking as a class method.

```
>>> with open('myPickleFile.pkl', 'rb') as f:
...   myThirdInstance = dill.load(f)
... 
>>> myThirdInstance.printV1()
4
```

Similarly, you can use `dump` externally to the instance, and it also works to create a new pickled instance.